# Checking if pixel belongs to an image

Tags: image, matlab, pixel, belongs-to

I have written the following function that find if a pixel belongs to an image in `matlab`.

At the beginning, I wanted to test it as if a number in a set belongs to a vector like the following:

```
function traverse_pixels(img)
for i:1:length(img)
    c(i) = img(i)
end
```

But, when I run the following commands for example, I get the error shown at the end:

```
>> A = [ 34 565 456 535 34 54 5 5 4532 434 2345 234 32332434];
>> traverse_pixels(A);
??? Error: File: traverse_pixels.m Line: 2 Column: 6
Unexpected MATLAB operator.
```

Why is that? How can I fix the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that to test for equality you also need to input `c(i)` and you need to use `==` rather than `=`. Now you just assign something to the local variable `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the head of your for loop, it's supposed to be:

```
for i = 1:length(img)
```

Also, to check if an array contains a specific value you could use:

```
A = [1 2 3]
if sum(A==2)>0
    disp('there is at least one 2 in A')
end
```

This should be faster since no for loop is included.

Comment: Instead of `sum(x==k)>0` I would recommend the use of `any(x==k)`

Comment: I wasn't aware of that solution, that's even prettier.

Answer (score 2):

for i = 1:length(image)

silly error, not **:** , it is **=**